# How do I merge one commit of a branch to another branch - use case

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch `access-permission` at my local as well as in github remote. I made changes to it, committed locally and pushed into `access-permission` remote branch.

Now I require to merge this commit into another remote branch called `staging`. I do not have a `staging` branch locally.

I may possibly clone remote `staging` branch to my local, checkout to it, merge `access-permission` into it and finally commit to remote `staging` branch. But is this the right way to go? Is there any way to do this without having `staging` branch locally?

I don't have enough experience using `git` so got confused. Please advise.

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: have you tried the rebase option present in GIT ? Rebase takes from and onto where from will be your branch with code and onto shall be the branch where the code has to be merged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described **is** the correct way to do this. You'll have to have a local copy of the `staging` branch in order to actually merge between the two branches.

It is also the place where you would handle any possible conflicts durring the merge.

Comment: Thank you Lix! I will try now.

Comment: Btw, is there any way that I can merge from Branch-A into Branch-B in github.com after committing to Branch-A? I mean if I Create a Pull request on github, would I be able to merge myself?

Comment: You will be able to merge if you have the permissions to do so. This depends on the repository you are working on. If it is your repository or you are a member/contributor/admin to the repository you shouldn't have any issues merging it yourself.

Comment: I am a contributor and I can assign myself. Please see the screenshot I attached in my OP.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you are indeed able to create the pull request. Once it is created you will see a "merge pull request" button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: If you don't see or are unable to click the merge button then you do not have the required permissions and you will have to ask one of the repository admins/maintainer to merge it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help Lix! One (probably) last question. Does this matter which branch is in the left and which one is to the right? Like in the screenshot `staging` is selected from the left dropdown and `new-permission-and-access` in selected from the right one. I have latest code in `new-permission-and-access` which I need to merge into 'staging`. Sorry for asking such a childish question!

Comment: Not a childish question at all! It's probably one of the most important ones :)
What is labeled as the "base" branch will be the branch you are merging into. From your screenshot, the `staging` branch (on the left) is marked as "base" - so for this PR, you are wanting to merge *from* `new-permission...` *into* `staging`.

Comment: Thank you very much Lix. You are super helpful :)